# Add 1 bit to a string

Tags: python, string, md5, bit-manipulation

I'm looking for a way to  "append '1' bit to message" in Python, in order to recreate the MD5 algorithm mentioned [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Pseudocode).

This is what I've done, but the problem is that `msg` is actually a string:

```
msg.append(0x01)         
while len(msg)%56!=0: 
     msg.append(0x00)
```

What should I do?

Comment: If you're using Python 3, perhaps converting to `bytes` is useful? E.g., `bytes(msg.encode('utf-8'))`

Comment: for an md5 implementation in python see [this](http://python.net/~gherman/programs/md5py/md5py.py) script.

Comment: Why append at all? *Conceptually* MD5 asks you to append some stuff, but in reality you can just run the "message" through the algorithm first, and then run the "tail" through it separately (without resetting the state in between, of course).

Answer (score 0):

use `chr` to convert the byte values to strings. Then you can append them to `msg`.

```
msg += chr(0x01 << 8)
while len(msg)%56 != 0:
    msg += chr(0x00)
```

In Python 2.7, each character in an ASCII string is 8 bits large. So with this method, you're not truly adding "1 bit" each time. That's why it's necessary to left-shift the 1 argument eight times. Otherwise you would be adding `0b00000001` to the string instead of the desired `0b10000000`.